# How to connect to a xen console via Net::SSH (ruby)

Tags: ruby, ssh, xen

I'm trying to write some ruby code that could connect to a XenServer VMs console (via `/usr/lib/xen/bin/xenconsole`) by first SSHing into the Host server then accessing the VMs console from the command line.

To do this I'm using the ruby library `Net::SSH`.  I'm doing ok logging into the Host server via SSH and running the commands to get the DOM id of the VM.  The problem comes when I'm running the xenconsole command.  You have to press "enter" after the command to get dumped into the console, then you have to press `CTRL + ]` to exit the VM's console and get back to the Host's command line.

I'm using the code below, but it hangs at the "press enter" point and doesn't give any feedback from the SSH channel either as STDOUT or STDERR.  What can I do to get to the VM's console to execute commands on the VM?  Then how do I send the `CTRL + ]` characters?

```
def execute_remote_console(hostname, port, username, password, uuid)

begin

Net::SSH.start( hostname, username, :password => password, :port => port ) do |session|

  dom_list_line = session.exec! "list_domains | grep #{uuid}"
  if dom_list_line.match(/(\d+)/)
    dom_id = $1
    puts "found #{uuid} on DOM #{dom_id}"
  else
    raise "couldn't find DOM id"
  end

  console_command = "/usr/lib/xen/bin/xenconsole #{dom_id}"
  puts "connecting to console: #{console_command}"

  session.exec!( console_command ) do |ch,stream,data|

    puts "pressing (enter)"
    ch.send_data "\n"

    case stream
      when :stderr
        puts "E-> #{data}"
        ch.exec "cat /etc/hostname" do |chan, success|
          raise "could not execute command" unless success

          # "on_data" is called when the process writes something to stdout
          chan.on_data do |c, data|
            $STDOUT.print data
          end

          # "on_extended_data" is called when the process writes something to stderr
          chan.on_extended_data do |c, type, data|
            $STDERR.print data
          end

          chan.on_close { puts "done!" }
        end
      when :stdout
        puts "O-> #{data}"
      else
        puts" other: #{data}"
    end 

  end #end session.exec


end #end SSH.start


  rescue
    puts "\t\t\tok (#{$!.message})" 
  end 

end #end function
```

Comment: did you manage to use console with NET:SSH? I have similar problem, but with `vzctrl` command which is switching to some VM